# Get the memory of file as bits array c++

Tags: c++, memory

How can i read some file, for example "*.ppt".
And then parsing the memory to bits array, whether memory stream is the correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the structure of the file.  Altough you mention C++, this is general enough to do in most languages. The basic online is:

1) allocate memory to process the file.  Preferably the entire file, but if need to process large files you'll need to to change this a bit

2) read the file in to the allocated space.

3) create structures that define the header, trailer, and any data.

4) assign a pointer of the header ftp to the top of the file (casting will be necessary), and read the data elements of the header out. Figure out what is next, and map the correct structure and continue in a likewise manner.

You may need a pragma to turn of padding within the struct (some compilers like to pad the structure so that fields align on machine specific boundaries).

Processing bitwise tends to be  tougher.  Reading individual bytes also tends to make the code needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. You write it yourself, which will probably mean that you read in the file bytewise and use your knowledge about the format in order to generate an object of a proper class.
   How to do so depends on the format.
2. You get a library that does it for you. For some rather complex format like ppt, this is recommended, especially since this format will change at some point in the future.

If you feel that this does not answer your question, then specify your question. It is rather broad.